# Hadoop input split dump

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

When a particular task fails, can we get a dump of the input split on which this task is running so that we can run the job locally on that part of the input and remote debug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write info about input split in mapper's setup. Example for `FileInputFormat`:

```
    @Override
    protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        FileSplit inputSplit = (FileSplit) context.getInputSplit();
        System.out.println(inputSplit.toString());
    }
```

Comment: Will this give the physical location of split on the hdfs? We can copy it to local file system and then ship it to dev box for remote debug?

Comment: This will print something like `hdfs://server:port/path/to/file/in/hdfs:0+1000`, where 0+1000 - start and end positions of the split.